# Simple SQL question on assigning dates of interest

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given Table A, where the rows are each date enumerated for each ID
(it should be comprehensive, i.e ID=1 doesn't stop at 1/4/2020 like shown here, but rather it goes all the way until 2022):

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 |
| 1 | 1/2/2020 |
| 1 | 1/3/2020 |
| 1 | 1/4/2020 |
| 2 | 1/1/2020 |
| 2 | 1/2/2020 |

and Table B of special dates for a given ID:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/3/2019 |
| 1 | 1/2/2020 |
| 1 | 2/5/2020 |
| 1 | 1/10/2020 |
| 2 | 2/10/2020 |
| 2 | 4/11/2020 |

How would I create a new table that has for each row in table A, the most recent special date from table B?
e.g

| ID | Date | Most Recent Special Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 | 12/3/2019 |
| 1 | 1/2/2020 | 12/3/2019 |
| 1 | 1/3/2020 | 1/2/2020 |
| 1 | 1/4/2020 | 1/2/2020 |
| 2 | 1/1/2020 | Null |
| 2 | 4/2/2020 | 2/10/2020 |

I imagine you'd have to join on both ID and date, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables and use `MAX()`.

```
SELECT A.id, A.date, MAX(B.date) AS most_recent_special_date
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.id = B.id AND A.date > B.date
GROUP BY A.id, A.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Barmar's answer works nicely and fast, if you only want the single value from `table_b`, if there are other values you want from `table_b` moving the MAX into a QUALIFY allows retrieving all values from that row:

so with some CTE's for the data:

```
with table_a(ID,Date) as (
    select column1, to_date(column2, 'mm/dd/yyyy') from values
    (1, '1/1/2020'),
    (1, '1/2/2020'),
    (1, '1/3/2020'),
    (1, '1/4/2020'),
    (2, '1/1/2020'),
    (2, '1/2/2020'),
    (2, '4/2/2020')
), table_b(ID,Date) as (
    select column1, to_date(column2, 'mm/dd/yyyy') from values
   (1, '12/3/2019'),
   (1, '1/2/2020'),
   (1, '2/5/2020'),
   (1, '1/10/2020'),
   (2, '2/10/2020'),
   (2, '4/11/2020') 
)
```

we also have a difference in out joins depends if you want the most recent including today (the way I have done it `>=`), or not including today (the way Barmar did it `>`).

```
select 
    a.ID,
    a.Date,
    b.date as "Most Recent Special Date"
from table_a as a
left join table_b as b
    on a.id = b.id and a.date >= b.date
qualify b.date = max(b.date) over (partition by a.id, a.date);
```

gives:

| ID | DATE | Most Recent Special Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 2019-12-03 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-02 |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-02 |
| 1 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-02 |
| 2 | 2020-04-02 | 2020-02-10 |